# How do I use Magento2's Payment Module

Tags: magento2

What does the Magento Payment Module do in Magento 2.4? I want to create a payment method. How do I use this module

Comment: The above two payment methods seem to have different logic codes. Are there any differences between them。

Answer (score 1):

The Magento payment module in Magento 2.4 is a module that provides the necessary functionality to create and manage payment methods within your Magento store. This module includes pre-built payment methods such as PayPal, Braintree, and Authorize.net, as well as the ability to create custom payment methods.

To create a payment method using the Magento payment module, you can follow these general steps:

1. Create a new module in your Magento 2.4 installation using the Magento CLI or manually.
2. Define the payment method in your module's configuration files, specifying the necessary details such as the method code, title, and payment type.
3. Implement the necessary PHP classes to handle the payment method's functionality, such as processing payments, handling refunds, and displaying payment information to customers.
4. Configure the payment method in your Magento store's backend, specifying any additional settings or requirements.

Here are some resources that can help you get started with creating a payment method using the Magento payment module:

Magento 2.4 DevDocs: Payment Method Overview (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-method-overview.html)

Magento 2.4 DevDocs: Create a Payment Method (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-method-create.html)

Magento 2.4 DevDocs: Payment Gateway Integration (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html)

Comment: The above two payment methods seem to have different logic codes. Are there any differences between them

Comment: Which two payment methods you are talking about, can you please specify ?

Comment: S,P answer:https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-payment-method-in-magento-2/

Comment: There are two ways to do it：https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-payment-method-in-magento-2/  and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-method-create.html

Answer (score 1):

You can configure default payment method from adminpanel (backoffice).

**Settings** :

ADMIN > STORES > Settings (Configuration) > SALES > PAYMENT METHODS.

There you shoud enable and configure payment method.

You also can create custom payment method

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/#the-bottom-line

https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-payment-method-in-magento-2/

Comment: The above two payment methods seem to have different logic codes. Are there any differences between them

Comment: You need to update logic as your requirement. It's only show require files.

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-payment-method

May be it would help you. you can download and use it.

Comment: Thank you,but  use  this(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html) , I think very difficult。

Comment: Yes, It's little complicated, But if you learnt mageplaza sample payment module and try to modified it then you can get better idea.

Comment: May be you are looking for online payment method correct?